# Firefox same randon number on event call

Tags: javascript, firefox, random

I have a function `randomPlay` associated to event `onended` but the random number is always the same on Firefox. On Chrome it's okay. Anyone can explains why and how to fix?

```
 function randomPlay(){
    $("audio").html('<source src="'+srcArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * srcArray.length)]+'" type="audio/mpeg">');
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
    }
```

The element is this audio:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay onended="randomPlay();" ><source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the element to:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay onended="randonPlay();" src=""></audio>
```

and changed the function to:

```
function randonPlay(){
    $("audio").attr("src",srcArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * srcArray.length)]);
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
}
```

So all is fine now :) Thank You for your help all.
Anyway I also found a lib to generate random numbers [Chance.js](http://chancejs.com/)

Comment: See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972550/math-random-not-random

Comment: That really is strange, even MDN (the most authoritative source for MDN) says it should be seeded by time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the generator is seeded when the page loads.  See this post for some info:

Here:  [Math.random() - Not random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972550/math-random-not-random)

Comment: Thank You so much.
I debug after and found the Random isn't the real problem. Anyway I found this awesome lib to generate Random numbers [link](http://chancejs.com/) .